# represent as linear combination of two polys

Tags: polynomials

I want to know how can one represent $t=x^4+2x^2-3$ as linear combination of $p=x^6-1$ and $q=x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x-3$.
If I do, $A*p+B*q=t$, I get $A=0,B=1$. How to solve it?

Actual problem:
[image]

I can prove the first part by finding common GCD of all. But for later, why are they asking with such a surety then?

Comment: Do you really get $B = 1$? There should no such $B$. That's why $t$ can not be represented by a linear combination of $p$ & $q$.

Comment: There cannot be such linear combination. You cannot use $p$, because its degree is higher and cannot be compensated with any term from $q$. And, obviously, $q$ and $t$ are not proportional.

Comment: @AugSB: That's if the coefficients are real numbers; here they are polynomials.

Comment: @joriki : yes could be polys, as I am working with ideals.

Comment: @joriki Definitely, I was assuming scalar coefficients. After the edition, knowing that we are dealing with ideals, my comment does not make sense anymore.

Comment: @AugSB: no, fault was mine as I didn't specify complete information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the polynomials all have zeros at $\pm1$. Thus you can factor out $x^2-1$ and represent $t'=x^2+3$ using $q'=x^2+2x+3$ and $p'=x^4+x^2+1$.

Applying the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) yields

$$
x^4+x^2+1 = (x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+3)+(2x-5)\;,\\
x^2+2x+3= (2x-5)\left(\frac12x+\frac94\right)+\frac{57}4\\
$$

and thus

$$
\left(\frac12x+\frac94\right)(x^4+x^2+1)=\left(\frac12x+\frac94\right)(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+3)+(x^2+2x+3)-\frac{57}4\;,
$$

or

$$
(2x^3+5x^2-14x+22)q'-(2x+9)p'=57\;.
$$

Thus

\begin{align}
t'&=q'-2x\\
&{}=q'-\frac{2x}{57}\left((2x^3+5x^2-14x+22)q'-(2x+9)p'\right)\\
&{}=\frac1{57}\left((-4x^4-10x^3+28x^2-44x+57)q'+(4x^2+18x)p'\right)
\end{align}

and accordingly

$$
t=\frac1{57}\left((-4x^4-10x^3+28x^2-44x+57)q+(4x^2+18x)p\right)\;.
$$

Comment: Do you know of any algorithm to do this...or it has to be guessed every time ?

Comment: I checked now again, but I am afraid it is not a polynomial anymore. Could you please verify?

Comment: @Rorschach: You can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). A linear combination exists if and only if $q$ is a multiple of the $\gcd$ of $t$ and $p$; the extended Euclidean algorithm gives you the $\gcd$ as a linear combination of $t$ and $p$, and then you just have to divide $q$ by the $\gcd$ to get the missing factor.

Comment: @Rorschach: How do you mean, it's not a polynomial anymore? What isn't? $q$, $p$ and $t$ are polynomials, and I've written $q$ as a linear combination of $p$ and $t$ with polynomial coefficients. (Obviously you have to pull the factor $\frac27$ inside the parenthesis to get the coefficient polynomials explicitly.)

Comment: I need to represent `t` in terms of `p` and `q` which in this case will become $[t=\frac{2\cdot p\cdot x-7\cdot q}{2\cdot {{x}^{3}}-4\cdot x-7}]$ which is not a polynomial.

Comment: @Rorschach: Sorry, looks like I got them mixed up -- will correct shortly.

Comment: @Rorschach: OK, I've done the calculation with the polynomials in the right roles -- I hope everything is OK now?

Comment: yes now its fine, thanks :)

Comment: One can also use Singular CAS to get this done(see example 1.8.2),
https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kvDwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=linear+combination+of+ideals+singular&source=bl&ots=fCncd3K6nU&sig=Q-jJWQtXznE0zpxi8h3Wm7MUQ4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1hv362NPLAhVRcY4KHaILDtAQ6AEIMzAD#v=onepage&q=linear%20combination%20of%20ideals%20singular&f=false

Answer (score 0):

One can also address this problem using Grobner Basis.
Using GB it is possible to generate smaller polynomials multiples of which with other polynomials will give expected result. I am not writing a complete solution but an abstract answer,
(Using S-polynomials, one can find the following),

$f1=x^6-1$,

$f2=x^4+2x^3+2x^2-2x-3$,

$f3=f1-((x-1)^2+1)f2$

$f4=(2*f2-x*f3-9/2*f3)*(2/57)$

Now, $(x^4+2*x^2-3)=f2-2*x*f4$

From here it needs to be substituted in terms of $f1$ & $f2$ and the result is,
$(1/57) (f1(18x + 4 x^2) + f2 (57 - 44 x + 28 x^2 - 10 x^3 - 4 x^4))$